# Reducing the number of settimeouts

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am creating a new setTimeout for each element that has the class cycle-words. There is no reason why they could not all use the same setTimeout, but I am unsure how to achieve this:

```js
    var cycles = document.getElementsByClassName("cycle-words");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < cycles.length; i++) {
     createCycle(cycles[i]);
    }
    
    function createCycle(element) {
      var wordsCnt = 0;
      var words = element.getAttribute("data-words").split(",");
     
      setTimeout(function showWord() {
        element.innerHTML = words[wordsCnt];
        wordsCnt = (wordsCnt + 1) % words.length;
        setTimeout(showWord, 500);
      }, 500);
    }
```

```html
<div class="cycle-words" data-words="yes,no,maybe"></div>


<div class="cycle-words" data-words="hello,hi,hey"></div>
```

I want to use just one setTimeout for all elements with the cycle-words class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) so you only have 1 block of code. `setTimeout` just runs once, but `setInterval` runs until you stop it with `clearInterval`.

In this example I've also moved the word count into a data attribute of each element, so that they don't rely on having the same number of words (I added "Yo!" to the hello words, as an example).

```js
var cycles = document.getElementsByClassName("cycle-words");

setInterval(cycleWords, 500);

function cycleWords() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cycles.length; i++) {
        var element = cycles[i];

        // get the current wordsCnt value for this element
        var wordsCnt = parseInt(element.getAttribute("data-word-count") || 0, 10);

        var words = element.getAttribute("data-words").split(",");

        // set the text of the element            
        element.textContent = words[wordsCnt];

        // increment and set the wordsCnt attribute value for next time
        wordsCnt = (wordsCnt + 1) % words.length;
        element.setAttribute("data-word-count", wordsCnt);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="cycle-words" data-words="yes,no,maybe"></div>
<div class="cycle-words" data-words="hello,hi,hey,yo!"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, interesting approach, just not that keen on having to set another data attribute for the word count.

Comment: Really - why not?  That's the kind of thing that data attributes are for, and the code creates it so you don't even add it in the markup.  Are you looking for problems where they don't exist?

Comment: ah sorry, I now see you create it with setAttribute :)

Comment: Ah okay - fair enough.  I just thought it made sense to cater for variable word counts from the beginning, rather than build something and then find that restriction later on, when it became a problem.  That's just me though :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use just 1 `setTimeout` by passing all the elements to a single function which starts the cycle.

```js
function cycler(elements)
{
    setTimeout(function showWord() {
        for(var i = 0; i<elements.length;i++)
        {
            var element = elements[i];
            var words = element.getAttribute("data-words").split(",");
            var wordsCnt = element.wordsCnt || 0;
            element.innerHTML = words[wordsCnt];
            element.wordsCnt = (wordsCnt + 1) % words.length;
        }
        setTimeout(showWord, 500);
      }, 500);
}
var cycles = document.getElementsByClassName("cycle-words");
cycler(cycles);
```

```html
<div class="cycle-words" data-words="yes,no,maybe"></div>

<div class="cycle-words" data-words="hello,hi,hey"></div>
```

Comment: Not the guy who downvoted the answer is clearly using two set timeouts and in the first line it was mentioned _You could use just 1 setTimeout_

Comment: @weegee no, you can use 1 `setInterval` but if you use `setTimeout` you need 2. It makes very little difference overall.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your `showWord` function inside an array, and then loop the array on each `setTimeout`..

Also a head up, if you want to access data attributes, you can also do -> `element.dataset.words`, it's supported by all major browsers.

Below is your code modified to do this->

```js
var cycles = document.getElementsByClassName("cycle-words");

function createCycle(element) {
  var wordsCnt = 0;
  var words = element.dataset.words.split(",");
  function showWord() {
    element.innerHTML = words[wordsCnt];
    wordsCnt = (wordsCnt + 1) % words.length;
  }
  return showWord;
}

var showWordsFn = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cycles.length; i++) {
  showWordsFn.push(createCycle(cycles[i]));
}

function showWords() {
  for (var i = 0; i < showWordsFn.length; i += 1)
    showWordsFn[i]();
  setTimeout(showWords, 500);
}

showWords();
```

```html
<div class="cycle-words" data-words="yes,no,maybe"></div>


<div class="cycle-words" data-words="hello,hi,hey"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

setTimeout is a function
define it as

```
var s= setTimeout(function showWord() {
        element.innerHTML = words[wordsCnt];
        wordsCnt = (wordsCnt + 1) % words.length;
        setTimeout(showWord, 500);
      }, 500);
```

as global var and pass it when needed

Answer (score -1):

Why use `setTimeout()` at all? This can be done using a single `setInterval()` function. Assuming you just have 2 divs or it can be more, get the data of the div's in separate variables and then get their value, combine the resulting array and for each the values inside a **`setInterval()`** function.

The resulting code is simpler than the others. I've added extra information in comments below.

```js
let cycles = document.querySelector(".cycle-words") // first div
let cycles2 = document.querySelector(".cycle-words2") // second div
let arr1 = cycles.getAttribute("data-words").split(",") // first div's data in array 
let arr2 = cycles2.getAttribute("data-words").split(",") // second div's data in array 
// merge the array and then forEach
let i = 0
setInterval(() => { // set the interval
  let lim = Math.max(arr2.length,arr1.length) // get the maximum array length

  if (lim != i && arr1[i] && arr2[i]) { // check if value exists
    cycles.innerHTML = arr1[i] // add the values
    cycles2.innerHTML = arr2[i] // same here
  }
  i++ // increment i 
  if (lim == i) { // check if the lim is passed if it is then reset it
    i = 0
  }
}, 500)
```

```html
<div class="cycle-words" data-words="yes,no,maybe"></div>
<div class="cycle-words2" data-words="hello,hi,hey"></div>
```